# why I set i::before then FontAwesome will disappear

Tags: html, css

My English is weak, and below is my question.

I would like creat a menu buttom(mobile style), I have a question somewhere, when I set

`.menu-btn i::before{content: "\f00d";}` will cover `<i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>`, I want to knew why?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');


*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
} 

nav{
    height: 80px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 60px 0 100px;
}

nav ul{
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav .logo{
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 35px;
}

nav ul li{
    margin: 0 10px
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

nav ul .active a,
nav ul li a:hover{
    color: black;
    background-color:#fff;

}

nav #click,
nav .menu-btn i{
    display: none;
    font-size: 26px;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}


@media screen and (max-width:768px) {


    nav .menu-btn i{
        display: block;

    }

    nav #click:checked ~ .menu-btn i::before{
        content: "\f00d";
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
        font-weight: 900;    
    }



    nav #click:checked ~ ul{
        left: 0;
        transform: all 1s ease;
    }

    nav ul{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        position: fixed;
        top: 80px;
        left: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        text-align: center;
        
    }

    nav ul li{
        margin: 50px 0;
    }

    nav ul .active a,
    nav ul li a:hover{
    color: skyblue;
    background-color: black;
    }


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6c92ff04b8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-jLKHWM3JRmfMU0A5x5AkjWkw/EYfGUAGagvnfryNV3F9VqM98XiIH7VBGVoxVSc7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="20220319.css">
    <title>20220319-navbar</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">Brand</div>

        <input type="checkbox" id="click">
        <label for="click" class="menu-btn">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>         
        </label>
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Servises</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using a font called font-awesome. In that font, the character `\f0c9` means a hamburger, and `\f00d` means the cross icon. When you change the class, for example, `fa-plug` it's the character on before changes to `\f1e6` and so on

Comment: but the class is actually not changing only the `content`!

Comment: This is not the correct answer as @Dhaifallah points out, the class is not changing. The cross shows because of specificity.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your setting has a higher specificity than the one that the Fontawesome system has set.

When you apply the class fa-bars Fontawesome's CSS is:

```
.fa-bars:before, .fa-navicon:before {
    content: "\f0c9";
}
```

But you are applying:

```
.menu-btn i::before{content: "\f00d";}
```

This has higher specificity than the previous setting **because of the .menu-btn**

If you take that out and just have:

```
i::before{content: "\f00d";}
```

the hamburger icon will be shown.

You can read more about specificity on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity?msclkid=61aa9bd6a75411ec8740e7cdc651de7d)